# React-Modal-Image displaying off center image when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've imported the react-modal-image library into my project to view images in a modal when clicked. However when an image is clicked, it appears off center with most of the image offscreen and I don't know what is causing it. Here is an example of my image before it is clicked: [image]

And here it is afterwards: [image]

Below is the code where I use the npm package:

```
<div className="card home-card" key={item._id}>
        <h5 style={{ padding: "5px" }}>
          <Link
            to={
              item.postedBy._id !== state._id
                ? "/profile/" + item.postedBy._id
                : "/profile"
            }
          >
            {item.postedBy.name}
          </Link>
          {item.postedBy._id == state._id && (
            <i
              className="material-icons"
              style={{ float: "right", cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => deletePost(item._id)}
            >
              delete
            </i>
          )}
        </h5>
        <div className="card-image">
          <ModalImage
            small={item.photo}
            medium={item.photo}
            alt={item.title}
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was just wrapped inside a div it shouldn't have been in. Ugh.

```
<ModalImage
          className="card-image"
          small={item.photo}
          medium={item.photo}
          alt={item.title}
        />
```